Insert into local table SELECT from distributed table in clickhouse caused default.local_table at other node not exists error
I need select  data from some distributed and local table,   insert into another stand alone local table。I use sql like this: INSERT into local_table SELECT FROM distributed_table WHERE ... . The SELECT clause can execute succesfully. But the whole sql  executing at local table node cause an error: clickhouse exception code:1002,host=12.27.6.124,port=8123;code=60,Exception:receieved from 12.27.6.123:9000,exception :table default.local_able doesnt exist. The local table is already created on 12.27.6.124.
12.27.6.124 is my local table node , 12.27.6.123 and 12.27.6.124 are  my cluster  nodes.
Why does the cluster node 12.27.6.123 involve the insert operation executing ?  how can I fix the problem?
clickhouse server version: 22.8.5.29
The problem can be fixed by changing local_table to distributed table. But it may cause lots of  sql rewriting.

"exception :table default.local_able doesnt exist" typo "local_able"?

Seems the server version is pretty old, really need to update as many updates and bugs fixed in every iteration.

Always use db.table clause or db.table AS alias
INSERT INTO database.local_table SELECT FROM database.distributed_table WHERE ...
looks like your <remote_servers> definition doesn't contains <secret>
this means you execute your query in initiator node with different user and security context with user which used to execute select from underlying table from distributed on remote servers with different default database value

The solution is not suitable for my scene. I use Spring Data JPA framework, the db name is  set by framework automatically from config file.

sorry, stackoverflow skip formatting for <secret> in my answer
you need to figure out where exactly your framework setup database
do you mean it setup connection parameter database?
try to look into system.query_log in each nodes use WHERE initial_query_id=XXX ... and figure out with settings which used fo query execution
